# How to remove fabric plugin from xcode / mac

Tags: xcode, xcode7, twitter-fabric, xcode-plugin

I have installed the fabric plugin as a part of twitter application integration. then fabric app is getting crashed every time. so can anyone tell me how can i uninstall FABRIC plugin completely so i can start again the complete procedure. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

Fabric.app is just a standalone app, so you can remove it by finding Fabric.app on your machine and dragging it into the trash.

If you want, you can also remove the local cache by running this command:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac
```

Comment: Thanks for raising that up @livingtech, as we didn't have a plugin for Fabric on macOS at the time the question was asked, I assumed that the developer was talking about Fabric.app.

Answer (score 5):

To remove Fabric from xcode, go to build phases in Target and delete "Run script".
In AppDelegate, remove this line [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]]; from didFinishLaunch method.
Now remove

```
#import "Fabric/Fabric.h"
#import "Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h" // from the AppDelegate.m
```

Finally, delete "Fabrics" and "Crashlytics" framework from Project Navigator.

To delete Fabrics from Mac, simply go to Applications in Finder window. Find Fabrics and move to trash.